# Story ident : Red-headed (female) twins encounter reptilians in a parallel world

Tags: story-identification

I think this book was written in the 80's.

- The two main characters were identical adult female twins, probably in their mid-twenties
- They have red/auburn hair
- I remember a scene where they become the mirror of one another and inadvertently open a door into some kind of parallel universe
- There was a scene where they say crossed legged across from one another and went into a sort of hypnotic state staring into each other's eyes and that triggered the "door" to the parallel world.
- One of them became a reptilian, or was possessed by one.

Comment: Was this aimed at young adults or a more (ahem) mature audience? What kind of door was it? What do you remember about the reptilians? How old were the twins?

Comment: The twins were adult, I want to say mid twenties. I read it in high school but I don't think it was geared toward young adult. I think I remember there was sex... The twins WERE the door. There was a scene where they say crossed legged across from one another and went into a sort of hypnotic state staring into each other's eyes and that triggered the "door". And than one of them became a reptilian, or was possessed by one. Also one or both of them may have been an archeologist...